# defaultview not returning all rows

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I have a dataset. it has 32 rows.I am not applying any rowfilter to it.code is here

```
 private void SetPageNumbers(DataSet dsQuestion)
        {
            DataView dv = dsQuestion.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

It is showing only 4 rows in dv.
But I want all rows. What can be the reason behind it?

I also noticed that defaultview is showing Rowfilter as "SectionId=4".But I have defined this in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 private void SetPageNumbers(DataSet dsQuestion)
 {
   DataView dv = new DataView(dsQuestion.Tables[0]);
 }
```

Comment: It works.. Thanks... Can You answer why Defaultview got its value in different function. Is it attached to dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I done it by adding following line;
dtques.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;

Can anyone answer why Defaultview got its value in different function. Is it attached to dataset.